# Rails 4 - Paperclip - Pass image name as method parameter and remove it inside it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have several paperclip attachments in a Model. I want to pass the name of it as a parameter for a method and then set it to nil.

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :header_image
  has_attached_file :footer_image
end

class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
  def remove_image(image_name)
    @campaign.image_name = nil # <- I want to do something like this
  end
end
```

How to do something like this? Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it an update transaction?, Do you want to delete the image associated to such record?

Comment: Yes. I am interested on how to pass the image name as parameter to be able to delete (or whatever) it. I have several images and I don't want to DRY.